# Timer wrap-around problems

Tags: c++11, integer-overflow, c++-chrono

Is the following code correct

#### Adding an event:

```
pushEvent(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + dt, event_obj);
```

#### In event loop:

```
//...
auto now=std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
if(event.expireTime<=now)
    {
    event.fire();
    }
//...
```

I am somewhat worried about wrap-around behavior, as I know of at least two bugs [1] and [2], that was introduced due to wrap-around in time counters. What I think of could happen:

- The event fires *early*, since `std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + dt` will be a smaller than `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`
- The event fires *late*, since `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` may have a wrap-around already.

  [1] https://www.cnet.com/news/windows-may-crash-after-49-7-days/

  [2] https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/issues/150

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the range of `steady_clock::time_point` with `steady_clock::time_point::max().time_since_epoch()`.  This returns a `chrono::duration` which is the maximum amount of time since the `steady_clock` epoch.  The epoch itself is unspecified.  However this:

```
auto time_left = steady_clock::time_point::max() - steady_clock::now();
```

gives you the time left until `max()` is hit.  The exact units of `time_left` can be inspected with:

```
using D = decltype(time_left);
std::cout << D::period::num << '/' << D::period::den << '\n';
```

On every platform this outputs:

```
1/1000000000
```

which means the unit is nanoseconds.  So you could:

```
std::cout << time_left.count() << "ns\n";
```

If you're willing to use my [free, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), it will do that introspection for you and you can just do:

```
using date::operator<<;
std::cout << time_left << "\n";
```

For me this outputs:

```
9221890448824928278ns
```

which is about 292 years.  If your code were running on my platform it might wrap in 292 years.  Your platform is probably similar, and this is how you can test for that.

Comment: So the answer is, ***no**, but it does not matter, because the duration is long enough on all major platforms* ?

Comment: Don't take my word for it.  Use the tools described above to form your own (newly informed) conclusions.  Also `time_point::max()` as well as everything else, is all compile-time information, so you can `static_assert` on it.

Comment: According to my calculations, it is actually 29.2 years.

Comment: `2^63/(10^9 * 86400 * 365.2425) = 292.277...`